# Do we have any cordova plugins for aws-cognito-identity?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic4, amazon-cognito

Is there any plugins available for cordova to integrate aws-cognito-identity as the current project requires api calls should be done through the native sdk for security reasons.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [aws-user-pool plugin](https://github.com/happygts/cordova-plugin-aws-user-pool) does this help?

Comment: @Jake Thanks for your reply. I checked this plugin but I didn't start working with it. This plugin supports only ios platform. I am developing app for both ios and android.